# UKUU new kernel error: you need to load the kernel first

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kernel

I installed new kernel with UKUU on my Ubuntu 18.10 (kernel 4.15 running). However when I boot the computer and use advance boot options in GRUB 2.2, it shows me the error saying:

> error: you need to load the kernel first

Also in UKUU the default kernel installed with Ubuntu distribution is marked with Ubuntu logo, however the others including the one that I downloaded are marked with Linux penguin logo in the beginning of their name.

1. how can I load the kernel for the system?
2. How to make it as the default kernel to boot with?
3. Does having dual boot with windows have anything to do with it and making any problems or not?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. To fix it, I went into the UEFI and [disabled Secure Boot](https://www.appgeeker.com/recovery/disable-uefi-secure-boot-in-windows-10.html). After saving the settings and rebooting I was able to use the new kernel.